# Encoder->IsPasswordValid must implement interface \UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to validate user, I can't user FOSub bcz it's not compatible with Symfony 4, I am coding something mine.
I pass username and password through ajax to service. Method which trying to login user :

```
public function login($username, $password) {

$user = $this->entityManager->getRepository("App:Users")
    ->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
}

if(!$this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password)) {
    return new Response(
        'Username or Password not valid.',
        Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED,
        array('Content-type' => 'application/json')
    );
}
```

}

When I call this method I have error :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder::isPasswordValid() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, string given, called in /src/Service/Login.php on line 60

Why it's telling me that I have to implement some service when in Symfony documentation there is

> isPasswordValid(**string** $encoded, **string** $raw, string $salt), Checks a raw password against an encoded password.

I don't understand this...

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong docs, [PasswordEncoderInterface](https://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/PasswordEncoderInterface.html) has the definition you mention, but you should be looking at [UserPasswordEncoder](https://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/UserPasswordEncoder.html). Your User class needs to implement [UserInterface](https://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html).

Comment: @JimL my Class Users which is Entity already implements UserInterface : class Users implements UserInterface

Comment: Great! But as you see from the docs I link to `UserPasswordEncoder::isPasswordValid` expects two arguments, `UserInterface $user and string $plainPassword`. Not the `$hash, $plainPassword` you're sending it

Comment: just send `isPasswordValid($user, $password)` and you are done, @JimL is right you are looking at interface instead of implementation

Comment: That's true, so how I can create this UserInterface $user object?

Comment: The `$user` you receive from your repository will be a UserInterface object, if your User class is implementing that interface you can reference it with it :)

Comment: @JimL post it as an answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: @kunicmarko20 yes, I understand, when I create User it creates UserInterface automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're simply looking at the wrong docs, [PasswordEncoderInterface](https://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/PasswordEncoderInterface.html) has the definition you mention, but you should be looking at [UserPasswordEncoder](https://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/UserPasswordEncoder.html).

Your User class needs to implement [UserInterface](https://api.symfony.com/4.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.html).

`UserPasswordEncoder::isPasswordValid` expects two arguments, `UserInterface $user, string $plainPassword`. Not the `$hash, $plainPassword` you're sending it

```
if(!$this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password)) {
```